# Using only parts of XMM register for data transfer

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

I have an Assembler-Program that works on a Data structure in memory consisting of Tuples of 3 floats (3*32bit). I was wondering if I could optimize the copying of data with xmm registers.
Reading values from memory wouldn't be much of a problem as I could just load in 4*32bit, but is there any way that I can write only parts of an xmm register back to memory?
 The only thing I've found in the ISA documentation is that you can use a writemask but no explanation on how to do that.

Comment: As far as I know, writemask only applies to AVX512. If you found it referenced elsewhere please be specific. For copying single elements I doubt you'd have any advantage over a simple 64+32 bit copy. If possible you might consider padding your data to 4*32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only AVX512 has masked stores in general like `vmovups [rdi]{k1}, xmm0`.

**AVX1 has [`vmaskmovps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov)** which works basically the same way, but with a vector control-mask.  (e.g. `pcmpeqd xmm1,xmm1` / `psrldq xmm1, 4`).  But it costs multiple uops.  It does fault-suppression if the destination extends into another page, but it's potentially inefficient if it actually would have faulted.  It's fine if the 16-byte destination doesn't cross a page boundary, or even a cache-line boundary.  (It may trigger a spurious cache miss or have to replay the store uop on a cache-line split, even if it's only the masked part that touches another cache line.  I forget and haven't checked recently.)

You don't want SSE2 [`maskmovdqu`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/maskmovdqu); that has NT-store semantics so it evicts the destination from cache after writing.

---

Without masked loads/stores, you can often safely load extra data, if you know that the source object isn't right at the end of a page.

It's much less likely that you can *store* past the end of the destination without stepping on anything important.  (Unless you pad your struct with a dummy element to allow this, or it's in an array and you're about to store the next element anyway.)

You can use 2 stores to get 12 bytes written, one 8 byte and one 4 byte.  (Or two overlapping 8-byte stores if that's easier to shuffle).

```
;; SSE2
    movups   xmm0, [rsi]          ; loads 4 bytes past the end of your object

    movsd    [rdi], xmm0           ; 8 byte store of the low 2 elements
    unpckhpd xmm0, xmm0           ; extract the high half
    movss    [rdi+8], xmm0
```

If you're storing contiguously to an array of structs, you can just do a 16-byte store and overlap it with the next 16-byte store.  Just be careful about the very last element: peel that final iteration.

Or with SSE4.1  unpckhpd / movss can become

```
extractps  [rdi+8], xmm0, 2
```

([`extractps` has a r/m32 destination](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/extractps): you can't use it for extracting a scalar float to another XMM register, but it is useful for FP stores to memory.)

---

If your code ever makes a copy of a copy, you might want to do the 2 loads separately as well, so store-forwarding will work.

You can even use GP-integer registers like RAX and EDX for the 8 + 4 byte loads/stores.  (Prefer doing both loads first, then both stores, in case of overlap or 4k aliasing, so the CPU doesn't have to figure out that the 2nd load doesn't overlap with the first store).

Comment: If you are ok with storing the three elements at `[0, _ 2, 3]` instead of `[0, 1, 2, _]` you can safe the `unpckhpd` instruction: https://godbolt.org/z/3AcXOv -- this is of course incompatible with the overlapping load/store.

Comment: @chtz: right a `movhps` store that doesn't need a shuffle uop, just a pure store.  But a `movhps` *load* does need a port-5 uop to merge a new high half.  If you're going to do 2 separate loads, there's very little point doing them into the same register instead of making them fully independent.  Unless you're doing SIMD math on them while they're in a register.  Then yes, `[0, x,  1, 2]` makes sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the different approaches and the excellent explanation!